# How to get data from inner observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a code:

```
    this.cardDynamicFields$
      .pipe(
        filter((data) => !!data?.objectfieldsdescription),
        map((data) => data.objectfieldsdescription),
        mergeMap((fields) =>
          fields.map((field: any) => {
            const { iconClassPropName, classifierId } = field;
            return this.classificatorService
              .getClassifierRows(classifierId)
              .pipe(
                map((data) => data.find((el) => el.id === iconClassPropName))
              );
          })
        )
      )
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

The function

```
return this.classificatorService
              .getClassifierRows(classifierId);
```

returns a inner observable.

How to get this result in subscribe? I have tried mergeMap, but I always get Observable array in subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge or forkJoin the array.
Something like:

```
this.cardDynamicFields$.pipe(
  filter((data) => !!data?.objectfieldsdescription),
  map((data) => data.objectfieldsdescription),
  mergeMap((fields) => forkJoin(
    fields.map(({ iconClassPropName, classifierId }) => 
      this.classificatorService
        .getClassifierRows(classifierId)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => data.find((el) => el.id === iconClassPropName))
        )
    )
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);
```